# Controller and Form

Tags: 8

What's the key difference between:

```
amazing_forms_contribute:
  path: 'amazing-forms/contribute'
  defaults:
    **_form: '\Drupal\amazing_forms\Form\ContributeForm'**
    _title: 'Conribute page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

and

```
amazing_forms_contribute:
  path: 'amazing-forms/contribute'
  defaults:
    _**controller: '\Drupal\amazing_forms\Controller\ContributeForm::content'
link_id: 'arm.admin_product_variants_create'**
    _title: 'Conribute page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

When I should use a controller? And when I should use a form?

Can I combine both (use controller and form)?

What is their limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_form:` We use this explicitly when one expects a classname
implementing FormInterface.

`_controller:`It is used when one needs to return a renderable
array or an object. Hence, here we call a method from its
class (classname::method)

And **NO** you cannot use `_form and _controller` at the same time under
defaults: since  one routing only provides **one functionality at a
time**.

> See here to understand how the [structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643) are used and
>   why they were used.Also see [routing api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Routing!routing.api.php/group/routing/8.2.x#sec_controller) for a more detailed
>   understanding.

Comment: so, can i say, form is to make a form?
and _controller is just to present a content?

Comment: yes _form is to make a form and _controller is not only to present the method (in ur case content) its used to return renderable arrays and also response objects..should i add some links to the answer 2 make it clearer ?? @AnD

Comment: There is *always* exactly one controller. _form, _entity_form, _entity_view and so on are just short cuts that are mapped to a generic (entity) form controller.